# Using two dimensional array as Dapper parameter list

Tags: c#, dapper

In Dapper it is possible to query a list with where in using this code:

```cs
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Kind IN @Kind;";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    var invoices = connection.Query<Invoice>(sql, new {Kind = new[] {InvoiceKind.StoreInvoice, InvoiceKind.WebInvoice}}).ToList();
}
```

But I'd like to query a list of products by multiple suppliers and their product code. So to do this, I tried creating an array of arrays. This is my method in my repository:

```cs
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Product>> GetGroupedListByRelationIdAndProductCode(Dictionary<int, List<string>> productKeysByRelationId)
{
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Product>> list = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Product>>();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE 1=1 ";

    int i = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> productKeys in productKeysByRelationId)
    {
        sql = sql + " AND (ManufacturerRelationId = " + productKeys.Key + " AND ManufacturerProductCode in @ProductCodeList[" + i + "] )";
        ++i;
    }

    using (var conn = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();

        var param = new { ProductCodeList = productKeysByRelationId.Select(x => x.Value.ToArray()).ToArray() };

        var productsList = conn.Query<Product>(sql, param).ToList();

        if (productsList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var product in productsList)
            {
                list[product.ManufacturerRelationId][product.ManufacturerProductCode] = product;
            }
        }
    }


    return list;
}
```

This gives me this error though: `System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type.'`

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

If you have more than one item in your `productKeysByRelationId` you will end up getting SQL like:

```
WHERE 1=1 AND ManufacturerRelationId = 1 ... AND ManufacturerRelationId = 2
```

That's not likely to return any results, you need to sprinkle some OR's in there.

The error you are getting is because you have something like:

```
AND ManufacturerProductCode in @ProductCodeList[0]
```

Dapper cannot handle that. It mostly expects the query parameters to be an object with aptly named members of a few simple types or array.

Thankfully Dapper has a solution to that, DynamicParameters to the rescue!

You can construct your query like this:

```cs
var queryParams = new DynamicParameters();
foreach (var productKeys in productKeysByRelationId)
{
    sql = sql + $" ... AND ManufacturerProductCode in @ProductCodeList{i} )";
    queryParams.Add($"ProductCodeList{i}", productKeys.Value);
    i++;
}
```

Now you have your query parameters in the right format, so you can just do this:

```cs
var productsList = conn.Query<Product>(sql, queryParams).ToList();
```

That ought to fix it, but you really should try to parameterize the `ManufacturerRelationId` also. It's not just about SQL injection, there might be some SQL cache performance related things.
You might also gain some clarity in code by using the SqlBuilder from Dapper.Contrib.